# Are median values numeric or ordinal?

Tags: ordinal-data, count-data, median

I'm trying to set up the input data that I'd feed into my DL model and for the simplicity, I'm thinking of plugging in only the min/max/average values of the original data. (This is necessary for my purpose)

But my coworker told me that I'd be better to plug the **median** value of the original data, which I think is a little bit doubtful as it doesn't seem like an ordinary numeric data. I thought it's more like an ordinal data (where the rank matters), but I'm not quite sure about it.

Is there any consensus about how the median value should be deemed as?

Comment: The median is as "numeric" as the mean.  Regarding the model, it might be better to use the original data (changing the model accordingly).

Comment: The median would have whatever attribute the data had. If data are numeric, the median is a number.